# I can't get workbook.open to open a file it use to open with no changes to the code. Why is it giving an error?

Tags: excel, vba, file

I am writing a macro that relies on the information in another workbook. Yesterday I had it up and running where the code would allow the user to input a case number and it would build the workbook title  from there (for example "CaseDownload_72503") and open the workbook with that title. I come back to my computer today and I am getting the error "Run-time error '1004' Sorry, we couldn't find CaseDownload_72503.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?" I haven't changed the location or name of the workbook since yesterday and my code hasn't been altered. I am not sure why it can't find the workbook

I have tried moving the document to the desktop in an attempt to get it to find it. I have tried changing the title to see if I can use a different one to get it to open. And of course, I have closed all excel related windows and restarted the computer and nothing has changed.

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'               SECTION 1
' This section accepts the case
' number from the user and then
' finds the dcouments that
' correspond to that case number
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim casenum, filename As String

'accepts user input for the case number they wish to open the workbook 'for
casenum = InputBox("Enter the case number for which you would like to generate the email template.")
'concatenates the case number with the beginning of the file naming 'standard
filename = "CaseDownload_" & casenum
'opens the file that matches'
Workbooks.Open filename:=filename
```

It should very simply open the workbook with the name provided and then the (not included) code that follows just begins to grab information from the open workbook and put it into another. It won't find the workbook and says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe you need to add full path to document?

Comment: `filename = "CaseDownload_" & casenum` is not quite a filename, which is pretty much the problem in your case. Make sure `filename` is a valid filename, and it should work.

Comment: When you don't pass the full path, Excel will look in whatever is the "current directory" - if the file's not there you'll get that message.  Excel will not search for the file.

Comment: I'm going to give putting in the full pathway a go and see if that makes a difference. I am trying to make this as user friendly as possible so that no one has to edit the macro to run it. So, I was trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: The location of the document is "S:\z - Clarinet Download"  where the drive is the S drive and it is saved in a folder called "z - Clarinet Download" and the workbook name is "CaseDownload_72503". Does anyone know the syntax for the Workbook.Open command with this information given.

Comment: I tried workbook.open filename := "S:\z - Clarinet Download CaseDownload_72503.xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

Try opening with the **complete filespec**; something like:

```
Sub Marine()
    Dim casenum As String, filename As String

    casenum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter case number", Type:=1)
    filename = "CaseDownload_" & casenum
    Workbooks.Open filename:="c:\users\garys\desktop\" & filename & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks so much for the help!